# How to prevent filtering and going back to default result when button is clicked for the second time in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery

The first click of a button filters the table as it should. However the second click on the same button resets the table to default result.

I would like the second, consecutive click on the same button to do nothing, just keep the table filtered.

Only when you click a different button, should the table filter again.

BONUS QUESTION: How not to lose focus on a button when a click happens anywhere else on the screen?

Note: This code is not mine. I am a complete amateur in JS/JQuery and so I would appreciate a direct solution.

Thank you!

Here's the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Sprytny/71xbjpqm/5/

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('table').show();
    var filter;
    $('.filter').click(function () {
        if (filter == this.id) {
            $('tr').show();
            filter = undefined;
        } else {
            $('tr:not(.' + this.id + ')').hide();
            $('tr.' + this.id).show();
            filter = this.id;

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just disable the button after it is clicked, and enable it after another one is clicked?

Comment: "How not to lose focus on a button when a click happens anywhere else on the screen?" I recommend against messing with this. Pages should generally allow focus to work naturally. It's important for accessibility, and could cause weird bugs. Add a class to the button (using javascript) instead.

Comment: @Elydasian: Sounds good, however like I said my skills in this are close to 0 , so no idea how to implement this. Could you help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all the code you basically need to use to get the desired functionality:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('.filter').on('click', function () {
    $('tr.' + this.id).show();
    $('tr:not(.' + this.id + ')').hide();
  });
});
```

Every time you click on an element with a class of '.filter' it will grab that elements' ID and show the rows with a class equal to that ID, and hide those that do not match the criteria.

As far as the issue with keeping the focus is concerned. I suppose you'd like to keep the current filter highlighted to the user. As others have mentioned you shouldn't do that with the focus property. You can add a class on a filter if it's active and style it through the class. Something like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('.filter').on('click', function () {
    $('.active-filter').removeClass('active-filter')
    $(this).addClass('active-filter');
    $('tr.' + this.id).show();
    $('tr:not(.' + this.id + ')').hide();
  });
});
```